# Apache Impala: Project map<string, string> keys as individual columns

Tags: hadoop, impala

In Impala, is it possible to project map keys from a MAP as actual columns in the result set?  I'm ingesting a dataset where we can't know all the possible attributes ahead of time and so we're using a map column for maximum flexibility.  However, at query time we still want to pull those attributes out as their own column.

Simplified example below with a few unique keys (in reality there are hundreds of keys in our dataset)

Schema:

```
Column  |  Type
-------------------
name    |  STRING
props   |  MAP<string, string>
```

Raw Table:

```
Name    |  Props
-----------------
Bob     |  {"age": "39", "fav_color": "green"}
Alice   |  {"fav_animal": "dog", "fav_color": "blue"}
```

Desired result:

```
name    |  age  |  fav_color    |  fav_animal
----------------------------------------------
Bob     |  39   |  green        |  NULL
Alice   |  NULL |  blue         |  dog
```

I can get all the results in a row-oriented manner by

select name, props.key, props.value from table, table.props props;

But, I've not been able to figure out how to make those keys from the MAP type column into their own columns.  Is there a efficient way to do this in Impala?

*(I'm open to writing a custom UDF but Impala UDFs cannot accept complex types like MAP :( unfortunately )*

Comment: In Hive, this is quite easy with something like `select name, props["age"], props["fav_color"], props["fav_animal"] from table`, but there does not seem to be an equivalent in Impala SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this using struct data type in Impala (CDH 5.13). Below is the set of steps i followed. Note that Impala supports struct data type in parquet format only. So I used Hive to create the table and load data into it and used Impala to query the same.

### Hive

```
create table raw_table_parq (
 name string,
 details struct < age: STRING, fav_color: STRING, fav_animal: STRING >
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '$'
STORED AS PARQUET;

testfile.csv
'Bob',39$'green'$''
'Alice',''$'blue'$'dog'
```

created a text file based staging table first, loaded csv into the staging table and then used "Insert into" to load table into parquet table. Once data was loaded into desired table used below query in Impala:

```
[quickstart.cloudera:21000] > select name, details.age, details.fav_color, details.fav_animal from test.raw_table_parq;
Query submitted at: 2019-12-30 06:31:09 (Coordinator: http://quickstart.cloudera:25000)
Query progress can be monitored at: http://quickstart.cloudera:25000/query_plan?query_id=2f436ff7e3301734:f6f0a75700000000
+---------+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| name    | details.age | details.fav_color | details.fav_animal |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| 'Bob'   | 39          | 'green'           | ''                 |
| 'Alice' | ''          | 'blue'            | 'dog'              |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
Fetched 2 row(s) in 0.13s
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works for a STRUCT type, however I have to use a map because the set of keys are unknown and can change dynamically.  I need to accomplish the same result with a MAP<string, string> type

Answer (score 0):

Found a potential solution, but it is very slow and cumbersome for a large number of attributes.  Query below pulls 2 attributes out into separate columns.

Prefer to find a more performant and simpler solution, if possible.

```
select 
    a1.name,
    a1.age,
    a2.fav_animal
from 
(   select
        t1.name,
        case t1.attr
            when 'age' then t1.value
        end `age` 
    from (
        select
            name,
            a.key attr,
            a.value value
        from
            mytable, mytable.props a
        where 
            a.key = 'age'
    ) t1
) 
a1 left join 
(   select
        t2.name,
        case t2.attr
            when 'fav_animal' then t2.value
        end `fav_animal` 
    from (
        select
            name,
            a.key attr,
            a.value value
        from
            mytable, mytable.props a
        where 
            a.key = 'fav_animal'
    ) t2
) 
a2 on a1.name = a2.name
limit 10;
```